# How to use ActiveRecord (without Rails) with database that doesn't have primary keys

Tags: ruby, sql-server, activerecord

I now writing automation program for system based on MSSQL Server, using Ruby 1.9.3 and ActiveRecord 3.1.6 without Rails.

Tables have nonstandard ids (`stk_id`, `urb_id`, instead of `id`), also some tables haven't primary keys.

Before I added column `id` and set it as primary key my program worked very slowly. I waited nearly 3 minutes while the program makes two operations of selection and some little processing in table with 9000 records. But when I added column `id` and set it as primary key, these operations were finished in less then 10 secs.

Yet another problem I found in deletion operation: it doesn't work at all without primary key in table. Error when trying to delete without primary key:

> undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

I can't modify the table structure of the production database. Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem without adding `id` columns and setting primary keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark: A database without primary keys is BAD !

http://www.helium.com/items/1539899-why-a-relational-database-needs-a-primary-key

Using nonstandard keys is no problem, just use self.primary_key = "stk_id"

You may also use composite_primary_keys: 
https://github.com/drnic/composite_primary_keys

Comment: Yes, I know, it's bad. Keys were added in tables where they needs.
Also I'm added self.primarky_key => "urb_ID" in my models.
Thanks. All works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Create indexed views on each of the tables with no primary key. A unique clustered index as well as other indexes as needed can be applied. Including a single table in the view should prevent you from violating the many conditions an indexed view requires/prohibits.

Comment: I also recommend this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into using [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) instead of ActiveRecord. It is not opinionated about the database schema like ActiveRecord is and may be easier to use with a database schema you can't modify.

Comment: Yes, I looked at Sequel. But 70% of project was written with ActiveRecord. Only three tables from two hundreds  were without primary keys. Maybe, because it's standalone tables not related with other ones.